# Rails 3 NoMethodError undefined method `name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I call comment.save on a comment object i get an error, any help debugging this?

Here is the output:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Comment:0x107b4c280>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:224:in `read_attribute_for_validation'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:224:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:224:in `add_on_blank'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:223:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/errors.rb:223:in `add_on_blank'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:9:in `validate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:314:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:314:in `_callback_before_1143'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/validations.rb:212:in `run_validations!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:67:in `run_validations!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:67:in `run_validations!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:55:in `valid?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:75:in `perform_validations'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
    from (irb):645
    from :0>>
```

...

this happens after running:

```
c = event.comment.new
c.body = "test comment"
c.save
```

I've read a lot of threads saying that this is an issue with Rails version and Rubygems version but I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Add your model definitions to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the following:

1. you have a show or index view with a call to name i.e `comment.name`
2. you have a validation on name in your comments model

but hard to tell from the info you have given. where do you get the error?

Comment: yes, #2 is correct. thanks for that. i wasn't careful to update my model after migrating. my model still contained a 'name' field that i was validating in the model. just gotta get used to rails errors :) thanks again.